# ActiveMQ Network of Brokers pull message from broker 1

Tags: activemq-classic

I am very new to ActiveMQ and I try to understand if I can achieve the following:

I have a producer which publishes messages to broker 1. In a secure network there is a broker 2 and the receiver. The connection between broker 1 and broker 2 can only be in the direction from broker 2 towards broker 1, because I can only communicate out of the secure network, but not in it.
All the documentation about network of brokers just show the way depicted in the following picture (found on https://dzone.com/articles/active-mq-network-brokers)
[image]

I need something similar, but the connection should be from broker-2 to broker-1.

Is something like this possible? Maybe with a polling from broker-2 to broker-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Have Broker2 connect to Broker1 and establish a duplex connection

```
<networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://broker1:61616)" duplex="true" ... >
```

see: [Network of Brokers](https://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html)

Comment: but isn't that the same as if broker1 would establish the connection?

Comment: No. With duplex, broker2 initiates the connection, then registers the consumer for the receiver for messages to flow from broker1 to broker2. This is one of the exact use cases for duplex mode.